# GTM custom JS trigger

Tags: javascript, triggers, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create a custom JS trigger im my Google Tag Manager, but I just can't get it fired.

I want the trigger to fire whenever a certain element is displayed on the screen (I don't have access to the whole code, I try to do it using tag manager only). I've defined a variable called 'Is Category Page' which looks like this:

```
function() {
  var isCategoryPage = document.getElementsByClassName("category-products")[0] === undefined ? false : true;
  console.log('is category page?', isCategoryPage);
  return isCategoryPage;
}
```

And my trigger rule looks like this- [GTM print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofbFS.jpg).

I can see 'true' printed to my console, but the trigger is not fired. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one for your trigger to work the actual event is missing - "event" is a key that needs to be pushed to the datalayer (GTMs "push" implementation scans incoming data for the "event" keywords and updates GTMs internal variables based on that), the value is then used as the name of the custom event. I do not see that anywhere in your example.

I suggest you use a different trigger - fire the trigger at DOM Ready (since you are reading DOM elements you need to be sure that they are present), select "fire on some DOM Ready events" and then enter your condition like in your existing example.